# Changing name of file until it is unique

Tags: python

I have a script that downloads files (pdfs, docs, etc) from a predetermined list of web pages.  I want to edit my script to alter the names of files with a trailing `_x` if the file name already exists, since it's possible files from different pages will share the same filename but contain different contents, and `urlretrieve()` appears to automatically overwrite existing files.

So far, I have:

```
urlfile = 'https://www.foo.com/foo/foo/foo.pdf'
filename = urlfile.split('/')[-1]
filename = foo.pdf
if os.path.exists(filename):
    filename = filename('.')[0] + '_' + 1
```

That works fine for one occurrence, but it looks like after one `foo_1.pdf` it will start saving as `foo_1_1.pdf`, and so on.  I would like to save the files as `foo_1.pdf`, `foo_2.pdf`, and so on.

Can anybody point me in the right direction on how to I can ensure that file names are stored in the correct fashion as the script runs?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `if` use `while` and increment an `index` that you append (instead of `1`)

Comment: Your code sample cannot possibly run. Please provide a short, valid program that demonstrates the problem you are having. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://SSCCE.ORG/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you want is something like this:

```
    curName = "foo_0.pdf"

    while os.path.exists(curName):
        num = int(curName.split('.')[0].split('_')[1])
        curName = "foo_{}.pdf".format(str(num+1))
```

Here's the general scheme:

1. Assume you start from the first file name (`foo_0.pdf`)
2. Check if that name is taken
3. If it is, iterate the name by 1
4. Continue looping until you find a name that isn't taken

**One alternative:**  Generate a list of file numbers that are in use, and update it as needed.  If it's sorted you can say `name = "foo_{}.pdf".format(flist[-1]+1)`.  This has the advantage that you don't have to run through all the files every time (as the above solution does).  However, you need to keep the list of numbers in memory.  Additionally, this will not fill any gaps in the numbers

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the [tempfile module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html):

```
fileobj = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pdf', prefix='', delete = False)
```

Now your filename will be available in fileobj.name and you can manipulate to your heart's content. As an added benefit, this is cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def uniquify(path, sep=''):
    path = os.path.normpath(path)
    num = 0
    newpath = path
    dirname, basename = os.path.split(path)
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(basename)
    while os.path.exists(newpath):
        newpath = os.path.join(dirname, '{f}{s}{n:d}{e}'
                               .format(f=filename, s=sep, n=num, e=ext))
        num += 1
    return newpath

filename = uniquify('foo.pdf', sep='_')
```

Possible problems with this include:

1. If you call to uniquify many many thousands of times with the same
   path, each subsequent call may get a bit slower since the
   `while-loop` starts checking from `num=0` each time.
2. `uniquify` is vulnerable to race conditions whereby a file may not
   exist at the time `os.path.exists` is called, but may exist at the
   time you use the value returned by uniquify. Use
   `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` to avoid this problem. You won't get
   incremental numbering, but you will get files with unique names,
   guaranteed not to already exist. You could use the `prefix` parameter to
   specify the original name of the file. For example,

   ```
   import tempfile
   import os    
   def uniquify(path, sep='_', mode='w'):
       path = os.path.normpath(path)
       if os.path.exists(path):
           dirname, basename = os.path.split(path)
           filename, ext = os.path.splitext(basename)
           return tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix=filename+sep, suffix=ext, delete=False,
                                              dir=dirname, mode=mode)
       else:
           return open(path, mode)
   ```

   Which could be used like this:

   ```
   In [141]: f = uniquify('/tmp/foo.pdf')       
   In [142]: f.name
   Out[142]: '/tmp/foo_34cvy1.pdf'
   ```

   Note that to prevent a race-condition, the opened filehandle -- not merely the name of the file -- is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with multiple pages, this seeems more like a "global archive" than a per-page archive.  For a per-page archive, I would go with the answer from @wnnmaw

For a global archive, I would take a different approch...

1. Create a directory for each filename
2. Store the file in the directory as "1" + extension
3. write the current "number" to the directory as "_files.txt"
4. additional files are written as 2,3,4,etc and increment the value in _files.txt

The benefits of this:

- The directory is the original filename.  If you keep turning "Example-1.pdf" into "Example-2.pdf" you run into a possibility where you download a real "Example-2.pdf", and can't associate it to the original filename.
- You can grab the number of like-named files either by reading _files.txt or counting the number of files in the directory.

Personally, I'd also suggest storing the files in a tiered bucketing system, so that you don't have too many files/directories in any one directory (hundreds of files makes it annoying as a user, thousands of files can affect OS performance ).  A bucketing system might turn a filename into a hexdigest, then drop the file into `/%s/%s/%s" % ( hex[0:3], hex[3:6], filename ).  The hexdigest is used to give you a more even distribution of characters.